# Merging data from different sources with different types

Tags: f#

I have four data sources that are related by a common ID (incrementing integer).

One data source `P` is always available and the three others `L`'s may or may not be available for a given ID (i.e. ID's are not guaranteed to exist) and are received over the internet and are distinguishable by their IP address.

I gather the data sources over some interval and then I would like to join them using their ID's.

My mental model is something like this

- The data from source `P` in the interval `P: List<'T>`
- The data from all `L` sources: `L: List<Dictionary<string, 'U>>`
- Get the ID from source `P` `a: 'T -> int`
- Get the ID from `L` source `b: 'U -> int`
- The resulting type where data is combined `'V = {Id: int; P: 'T; L: Dictionary<string, 'U> }`
- The result `R: List<'V>`

Before I run amok using hash sets and whatnot, it would be nice to get some ideas on how to do this. Maybe there are some cool F# features that makes this really easy.

Comment: The question is not completely clear - you write that Ls maybe available for a given ID, but your call to get ID from L is keyed by `'U`?

Comment: @AntonSchwaighofer Yes data from the `L` sources are all of the same type, `'U`, and are assumed to contain the ID. `a` and `b` extract the ID from the data types `'T` and `'U`.

Comment: If I assume you mean `a: int -> 'T`, and for `b` accordingly, I would rather model that as `{ Id: int; P: 'T; L: Map<string,'U option>}`. I don't see why you need a list of dictionaries?

Comment: @AntonSchwaighofer You're right. The list of dictionaries in the resulting type is an error. The list is in the `R`. Updated the Q.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can translate your domain model into types in F# a bit more directly.

> One data source P is always available and the three others L's may or
>   may not be available for a given ID (i.e. ID's are not guaranteed to
>   exist) and are received over the internet and are distinguishable by
>   their IP address.

This describes a record type in F# pretty neatly.

```
type MyDataSources = 
    {Id: int;
     P : MyDataSource;
     L1: MyOtherDataSource option;
     L2: MyOtherDataSource option;
     L3: MyOtherDataSource option;}
```

> I gather the data sources over some interval and then I would like to
>   join them using their ID's.

So, we need another record type for the data.

```
type JoinedData<'T, 'U> =
    {PData : 'T list;
     L1Data : 'U list option;
     L2Data : 'U list option;
     L3Data : 'U list option;}
```

We then just need a function that takes the data sources and populates the data.

```
let populateDataFromSources dataSources =
    {PData = getDataFrom dataSources.P // replace with whatever logic you want here
     ....
    }
```

If needed, your `getDataFrom` function could take the `Id` from your data source as an argument and filter for data returned which relates to that `Id` (for example).

Comment: I appreciate the logic here, but it seems to me that the problem with merging is deferred to the `populateDataFromSources`. I was thinking maybe there is a nice way to `left join` the sources so that I won't have to write the merge from scratch.

Comment: @kasperhj You can just strongly reference the data sources using the above approach, you don't need any kind of complex `Id` based joins/merges.  In the absolute worst case, the data sources return data applicable to multiple `Id`s, in which case the only logic you need is `filter`.

Comment: But how would you construct `MyDataSources`? `P` has and id that must be matched with `Lx`.

Comment: It turns out that your approach can be combined with an agent to render a rather elegant solution. Nice!